# Set the Tooltip Delay Time for a Particular Component in Java Swing

Tags: java, performance, swing, user-interface, tooltip

I'm trying to set tooltips on a `JEditorPane`. The method which I use to determine what tooltip text to show is fairly CPU intensive - and so I would like to only show it after the mouse has stopped for a short amount of time - say 1 second.

I know I can use `ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setInitialDelay()`, however this will set the delay time for tooltips on all swing components at once and I don't want this.

Comment: What do you do present in the tooltip which cannot be computed in a background thread?

Comment: Some sample code may be helpful.  I could perhaps give an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I want to change the content of the tooltip depending on what word the user is hovering over. The task of populating the contents of the tooltip is quite expensive, so I only want to perform that computation if the user has stalled over a word.

Comment: Right now I'm using the MouseMotionListener and I'm changing the tooltip contents in the mouseMoved() handler. I suppose what you are suggesting is that I fire off a thread to work out the tooltip contents and then display that when its ready

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I would recommend doing the CPU intensive task on another thread so it doesn't interrupt normal GUI tasks.

That would be a better solution. (instead of trying to circumvent the problem)

***Edit*** You could possibly calculate the tootips for every word in the `JEditorPane` and store them in a `Map`.  Then all you would have to do is access the tootip out of the `Map` if it changes.

Ideally people won't be moving the mouse and typing at the same time.  So, you can calculate the tootlips when the text changes, and just pull them from the `Map` on `mouseMoved()`.

Comment: Your edit is a very good suggestion. I'm not sure if it will work because it is actually a debugger I am working on and so the values that are put in the map are subject to change - it's a great idea though. I think your suggestion of computing the value in a thread is good too.

Comment: Yes I agree - some form of caching the answer as the mouse moves and retrieving it when the user stops could solve my problem. I will give it a try tomorrow - I'll set your answer to accepted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 32):

If what you want is to make the tooltip dismiss delay much longer for a specific component, then this is a nice hack:

(kudos to tech at http://tech.chitgoks.com/2010/05/31/disable-tooltip-delay-in-java-swing/)

```
private final int defaultDismissTimeout = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().getDismissDelay();

addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(60000);
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(defaultDismissTimeout);
  }
});
```

Comment: +1, but I made a change. I took getting the default timeout outside of `mouseEntered()`, because it has the potential to screw things up if you're setting defaultDismissTimeout multiple times (what if the user has multiple components side by side where they've changed the timeout? They could lose the default timeout entirely by moving from one to another.) Ideally, it seems the defaultDismissTimeout should go someplace global to ensure it's set just once, at the initialization of the entire application.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, In the linked blog, defaultDismissTimeout was marked as final, which I suppose is how they got around the multiple setting.

Comment: @BuhBuh - I edited the answer here to take the defaultDismissTimeout outside of the listener, but in the actual code I wrote based on this answer, I decided to make it a static final variable for my component. If you'd like to see the actual values that are default, take a look at lines 85-91 here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.java

Answer (score 7):

You can show the popup yourself. Listen for mouseMoved() events, start/stop the timer and then show popup with the following code:

First you need PopupFactory, Popup, and ToolTip:

```
private PopupFactory popupFactory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
private Popup popup;
private JToolTip toolTip = jEditorPane.createToolTip();
```

then, to show or hide the toolTip:

```
private void showToolTip(MouseEvent e) {
    toolTip.setTipText(...);
    int x = e.getXOnScreen();
    int y = e.getYOnScreen();
    popup = popupFactory.getPopup(jEditorPane, toolTip, x, y);
    popup.show();
}

private void hideToolTip() {
    if (popup != null)
        popup.hide();
}
```

This will give you adjustable delay and a lot of troubles :)

Comment: In my case, if you hover above an icon at the start of the status bar, a tooltip pops up with the past 'n' messages.  As long as you keep the mouse within the tooltip bounds it stays.  But I wanted to control all timing aspects without changing the global tooltip timings.

In my opinion, your solution seems like a much better alternative than the accepted answer, but hey its only my two cents?  

Thanks for this solution Piligrim, I'll be trying it very shortly!

Comment: I haven't looked at this thread for a long time but I like your suggestion. I never got a chance to finish this project so I will be trying this again soon. I will give your idea a shot :)

Comment: For me it works perfectly. Indeed this should be preferred.

Comment: Yes, very nice. I recommend adding 2 to x and y respectively. This helps when you are binding the tooltip to mouseEntered/mouseExited because you can get an infinite loop of showing/hiding the popup otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here is code that is based on the post by Noel. It takes that prior art and wraps it in a new class where the default is stored statically. Just in case anyone may benefit:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Provides customizable tooltip timeouts for a {@link javax.swing.JComponent}.
 *
 * @see ToolTipManager#setDismissDelay(int).
 */
public final class CustomTooltipDelayer extends MouseAdapter
{
  private static final int defaultDismissTimeout = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().getDismissDelay();

  private final int _delay;

  /**
   * Override the tooltip timeout for the given component in raw millis.
   *
   * @param component target
   * @param delay the timeout duration in milliseconds
   */
  public static CustomTooltipDelayer attach(JComponent component, int delay)
  {
    CustomTooltipDelayer delayer = new CustomTooltipDelayer(delay);
    component.addMouseListener( delayer );
    return delayer;
  }

  /**
   * Override the tooltip timeout for the given component as a ratio of the JVM-wide default.
   *
   * @param component target
   * @param ratio the timeout duration as a ratio of the default
   */
  public static CustomTooltipDelayer attach(JComponent component, float ratio)
  {
    return attach( component, (int)(defaultDismissTimeout * ratio) );
  }

  /** Use factory method {@link #attach(JComponent, int)} */
  private CustomTooltipDelayer(int delay)
  {
    _delay = delay;
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e )
  {
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(_delay);
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e )
  {
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(defaultDismissTimeout);
  }
}
```