# How can I delay a MouseOver in Java?

Tags: java, swing, timer, mouseover, wait

I've got a short question and I hope somebody can help me.

Please look at the following code snippet:

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
   //wait 2 seconds.
   //if no other mouseEntered-event occurs, execute the following line
   //otherwise restart, counting the 2 seconds.
   foo();
}
```

Can somebody help me with that problem? I want to realize a behavior like an ToolTip: you enter a region with your mouse. If your mouse stays in that position, do something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start a [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) with a delay of 2 seconds in your `mouseEntered()` method that calls whatever it is you want to do.

Set up a new handler (`mouseExited()`) that stops the timer if it hasn't gone off.

Basically, you know the mouse is still there if `mouseExited()` hasn't been called. The timer will either go off in two seconds doing what you want or be cancelled if the mouse exits.

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer provided by [@Brian Roach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187801/how-can-i-delay-a-mouseover-in-java/8187834#8187834) is correct, there is yet another (and more succinct) way of achieving this. That is, using the [`ToolTipManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html).

Example:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;

public final class ToolTipDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setInitialDelay(2000);
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JToolTipButton());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final class JToolTipButton extends JButton{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5193366265809801639L;

        protected JToolTipButton(){
            super("I can haz tooltip?");
            setToolTipText("Hey man, get off me!");
        }
    }

}
```

By invoking [`setInitialDelay`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html#setInitialDelay%28int%29), I've changed the time the manager waits to display the tool tip from 750ms to 2000ms.

Note - Although I'm not sure, I think this may change the delay for ALL components ([guess I was right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190290/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-delay-time-of-tooltips-being-displayed-on-a-particular)), which may not be what you want..but it's still worth mentioning.