# MouseListener delay a bit mouseEntered

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I have a `JLabel` and I use a `MouseListener` on it. I use the known code:

```
jl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println("Entered")
    }
});
```

And the text `Entered` is printed when I enter the mouse on the `JLabel`. Everything is fine but I'd like to exist a bit of delay (like 1-2 seconds) by the time I enter the cursor on the `JLabel` and then the text to be printed. How can I accomplish this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delay a MouseOver in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187801/how-can-i-delay-a-mouseover-in-java)

Comment: You can use javax.swing.Timer. See examples on how you can use it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691339/adding-a-timer-and-displaying-label-text/13691413#13691413)

Comment: Why would you want to display text when a mouse enters the label? The solution will depend on the code to be executed within the MouseListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the single threaded nature of the Swing API and the  fact that the API is not thread safe, I'd recommend using a Swing `Timer` to inject a small delay between the event and your operation, for example...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //...
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false); // So you are notified only once per mouseEnter event

jl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
        timer.restart();
    }
});
```

This example will delay the calling of the `ActionListener` by 1 second every time the mouse triggers the `mouseEntered` event.  Note though, if the user exits and enters the label before the delay expires, it will be reset back to the start.

If you want some event to trigger 1 second after ANY `mouseEnter` event, then you could simply create a new Swing `Timer` on each `mouseEnter` event instead.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Somewhere in your program you need to create one:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService svc = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

Then in your mouse listener schedule a task:

```
jl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
        svc.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { System.out.println("Entered"); }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    }
});
```

I would separate some of the functionality out in to methods that are called by the anonymous inner classes.  Nesting the anonymous inner classes like this can quickly lead to hard-to-read and hard-to-maintain code.